# Warning Errors on Joomla Site

Tags: session, caching, joomla, connection, warnings

I have the following errors on my joomla site:

**1st Warning**: include_once(inc.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/74/9701074/html/index.php on line 2

**2nd Warning:** include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/74/9701074/html/index.php on line 2

**3rd Warning:** session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/74/9701074/html/index.php:2) in /home/content/74/9701074/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 532

When i check the **1st warning** i go to the path it indicates and find the following:
[image: 1stwarning]

So i see the 2 line indicates it searches for the inc.php file (which i believe contains the connection to the DB and etc) but then i **can't** find it.

Then i go to try solving the **2 warning** but i can't find that folder it points to.

And **3 warning** not idea how to solve that.

CAn you guys point me to the right direction please?

Comment: PHP 5.3 is extremely out of date.  I would see if you can change version in cPanel or contact host to move to at least PHP 5.6.  What version Joomla are you on?

Comment: hey @YellowWebMonkey thanks for ur comment. Definitley it is something with the version of Joomla. right now im in joomla 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has this similar issue: just go to the index.php file the warning displays and then comment that 2nd line, warning will be gone. Although not sure why the warnings appear but i guess it happens when joomla upgrades version:

[image: comment-2nd-line]

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to hide the errors, you can go to SYSTEM->Global Configuration->Server->Error Reporting and set to System Default or None.

As far as the actual issue, PHP 5.3 is extremely out of date. I would see if you can change version in cPanel or contact host to move to at least PHP 5.6.